# jQuery ajax serialize only 2 fields

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know how to serialize the whole form like in example below or one specific field of the form by just changing the line:

```
data: $('form').serialize(),
```

to

```
data: $('#input-field').serialize(),
```

.

```
$(document).on('input paste', '#soap', function () {
  $.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'/soap',
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     data: $('form').serialize(),
         success:function(data){
            $('input[id=msg]').val(data.msg);
         }
    });
});
```

But i want to serialize 2 input fields that have an id....how to do that?

Comment: [`$.param()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Way 1:** By comma separated selector you can serialize two fields together using following code

```
var seializedTwoFields = $('#input-field1,#input-field2').serialize();
```

**Way 2:** When you use the jQuery serialize() function, it simply turns your field into a string in the format a=1. So you can certainly apply this function to two fields and concatenate the result, with an & between them.

Please try this snippet.

```
var formfield1 = $('#input-field1').serialize();
var formfield2 = $('#input-field2').serialize();

var seializedTwoFields = formfield1+'&'+formfield2;
```

Comment: hmm...i'm using Laravel so i just wanted to send the both input fields to my controller through ajax and get them with $var1 = $request->number and $var2 = $request->code. This works fine with data: $('form').serialize(),

Comment: this with coma , should be perfect...i'll try that now

Comment: @lewis4u check my updated answer I have shared two ways.

Comment: the one with coma is great! like this data: $('#number, #code').serialize(), i didn't know you can put a coma between two ids or fields

Answer (score 0):

You can have a **complete object** from the serialized data like below:

```
var obj = {};
$('form').serializeArray().map(function (x) { obj[x.name] = x.value; });
```