# Serialize multiple specific input fields from different divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, serialization

I'd like to serialize some input fields from different divs (multi step form). Here is the code for better understanding:

```
<div class="page-1"> // serialize
    // input fields
</div>
<div class="page-2"> // don't serialize
    // input fields
</div>
<div class="page-3"> // serialize
    // input fields
</div>

form = $('form .page-1 input', 'form .page-3 input');
formData = form.serialize();
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: @random `form` don't shows any input field.

Comment: probably you are looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658958/jquery-ajax-serialize-only-2-fields

Comment: @mitkosoft worked for me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery ajax serialize only 2 fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658958/jquery-ajax-serialize-only-2-fields)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
form = $('form .page-1 input, form .page-3 input'); // notice the css selector
formData = form.serialize();
```

It happens because you are not selecting correctly the 2 html nodes, the correct format is the css format which is "firstElement, secondElement".
CodePen: https://codepen.io/OctavianParalescu/pen/NWqKjMR.

Comment: works like a charm. I will mark your answer as accepted in 5 minutes. You were too fast :).